# How to create a ServerSocket Object without the localhost address

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, serversocket

Hy guys, my code here to create a simple server works fine with the local host address(127.0.0.1). Here is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Zig z = new Zig();
        z.start();
    }
}
class Zig
{
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    InetAddress ia = null;
    Socket s = null;
    private static final int prt = 56540;
    Zig()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] addr = {127,0,0,1};
            ia = InetAddress.getByAddress(addr);
            SocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress(ia,prt);
            ss = new ServerSocket();
            ss.bind(sa);
            s = ss.accept();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Zig start()
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream i = s.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String str = null;
            while (str != "stp")
            {
                str = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(str);

            }
            br.close();
            isr.close();
            i.close();
            s.close();
            ss.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I use the router's IP - 192.168.8.1 instead of 127.0.0.1? I also tried the IP address from http://whatsmyip.org but still got this exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:329)
    at Zig.<init>(Main.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Zig.start(Main.java:38)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I wanted to create a simple server with that i can access remotely with another computer both having internet connection.
Or is there a way I can make communication between two computers over internet?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> > how can I use the router's IP - 192.168.8.1

You cannot use the router's IP. You should use the IP thats available in the system.

Note this error :

```
> java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
```

The `bind` is failing because the address isn't that of the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your 2 devices to communicate via LAN (local network) you can use the addresses your router assigned to these devices (that's the 192.168.8.X address you mentioned. EDIT: As Prabhu mentioned, use the devices IP Address, not the routers IP-Address! You can usually find the IPs your router assigned to connected devices in your routers admin-interface). Remember that your router might assign a different adress to the same devices in the future. Most routers come with a function that always assigns the same IP to a specific device. Also, some routers block communication between local devices (i.e. between wired and WiFi devives) for security reasons. Check your router's configuration for more information and configuration options!

If you want your devices to connect via internet you have to use your routers global IP-address (thats probably the one you found out using whatsmyip).

Additionally, your router usually just blocks incoming requests from the internet for security reasons. Again, your Router probably has a function called *Port forwarding*, which allows you to redirect requests to a specific device (and a specific port at that device) in your local network. Use this with care, as this opens (a part) of your routers built-in security mechanisms.

Finally, depending on your provider, you may have a IPv4 address (see [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)) that you share with other customers (So called DS-Lite ([Wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Dual-Stack_Lite_.28DS-Lite.29)). In this case, you're network is not reachable from the IPv4-internet at all and your only chance is to use the IPv6 Protocol (if available).

Hope that helps.